# Fixing RStudio's default par() settings

Tags: r, rstudio

Upon starting RStudio (v0.97.551 on OSX 10.8.4) running `plot(1:10, 1:10)` fails with `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`.  This seems unrelated to the other SO questions featuring this error message as it only happens in RStudio - R's basic GUI is unaffected.

`par()` yields:

```
> par()
$xlog
[1] FALSE

$ylog
[1] FALSE

$adj
[1] 0.5

$ann
[1] TRUE

$ask
[1] FALSE

$bg
[1] "white"

$bty
[1] "o"

$cex
[1] 1

$cex.axis
[1] 1

$cex.lab
[1] 1

$cex.main
[1] 1.2

$cex.sub
[1] 1

$cin
[1] 0.2000000 0.2666667

$col
[1] "black"

$col.axis
[1] "black"

$col.lab
[1] "black"

$col.main
[1] "black"

$col.sub
[1] "black"

$cra
[1] 14.4 19.2

$crt
[1] 0

$csi
[1] 0.2666667

$cxy
[1]  0.02915216 -0.46109510

$din
[1] 8.513889 1.875000

$err
[1] 0

$family
[1] ""

$fg
[1] "black"

$fig
[1] 0 1 0 1

$fin
[1] 8.513889 1.875000

$font
[1] 1

$font.axis
[1] 1

$font.lab
[1] 1

$font.main
[1] 2

$font.sub
[1] 1

$lab
[1] 5 5 7

$las
[1] 0

$lend
[1] "round"

$lheight
[1] 1

$ljoin
[1] "round"

$lmitre
[1] 10

$lty
[1] "solid"

$lwd
[1] 1

$mai
[1] 1.360000 1.093333 1.093333 0.560000

$mar
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1

$mex
[1] 1

$mfcol
[1] 1 1

$mfg
[1] 1 1 1 1

$mfrow
[1] 1 1

$mgp
[1] 3 1 0

$mkh
[1] 0.001

$new
[1] FALSE

$oma
[1] 0 0 0 0

$omd
[1] 0 1 0 1

$omi
[1] 0 0 0 0

$pch
[1] 1

$pin
[1]  6.8605556 -0.5783333

$plt
[1] 0.1284176 0.9342251 0.7253333 0.4168889

$ps
[1] 16

$pty
[1] "m"

$smo
[1] 1

$srt
[1] 0

$tck
[1] NA

$tcl
[1] -0.5

$usr
[1] 0 1 0 1

$xaxp
[1] 0 1 5

$xaxs
[1] "r"

$xaxt
[1] "s"

$xpd
[1] FALSE

$yaxp
[1] 0 1 5

$yaxs
[1] "r"

$yaxt
[1] "s"

$ylbias
[1] 0.2
```

Setting `par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))` stops the error message but messes up the plot (I think it pushes plot axes outside the viewable plot area).  In any case I don't see why this should be necessary - it should plot ok without the need to customise par.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and if there's any way to fix it?

Comment: I can see a tumbleweed badge coming my way!

Comment: How big is the plot window in RStudio? Did you try enlarging that and retrying the plot? Also, if it persists, did you try plotting with the standard graphics devices? `x11(); plot(1:10, 1:10)`? The only time I've gotten that error is when the plot window is too small.

Comment: Just looking back at this. I think you're right - it only happened on my laptop as I had that window minimised. Please add as answer and I'll close this off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plot window in RStudio is too small, you will get this error.

Keeping that in mind, two options to try are:

1. Enlarge the plot window :-)
2. Try plotting with the standard graphics device (which I believe should be `x11()` for you).

Answer (score 0):

After having set `par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))`, close and open a new graphical device:

```
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))    
dev.off()    
dev.new()
```